# What's wrong with asking a question which may involve opinions?

Tags: discussion

What's wrong with asking a question which may involve opinions?

For example, this question was put on hold.
["A, B or C" or "A, B, or C" or "A or B or C"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/47026/a-b-or-c-or-a-b-or-c-or-a-or-b-or-c)

If this site were about physics or mathematics, I could understand why such questions should be closed. However, this site is about the English language which is far from being an exact science.

Let's say there's a question asking whether a certain sentence is grammatical or not.
Whether it is grammatical or not often depends on scholars' opinions.

Comment: This may be relevant http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/

Answer (score 1):

The linked question is asking which is the best style.  That's not a matter of expertise,  that's really a matter of personal preference or the commonly accepted guidelines for a particular type of writing. There are subjective questions that are on topic, but this isn't one of them in my opinion. It might be if it were more specific,  like "Which style is the most accepted for writing an academic thesis?" That doesn't mention "best" and it asks for something that could be supported with facts or experience.

Comment: "*That's not a matter of expertise*"

Could you explain why you think so?

"*the commonly accepted guidelines for a particular type of writing*"

Could you explain what's wrong with asking about it?

Comment: @MakotoKato There are different recommendations for comma usage in different style guides. There is no "best" style for all types of writing; there is only the style that someone prefers for whatever reason.  There's nothing wrong with asking about it, but as the question is currently phrased, it is not on topic for this particular site.

Comment: Nicely put. Sometimes a question is closed, not because it "may involve opinions," but because it's so vaguely worded that there's not much else besides opinion. One more clarification should be made, too: there's absolutely NOTHING wrong with asking the question, just like there's nothing wrong with having a question put on hold. You don't lose rep for closed questions; you have an opportunity to hone them and make them more on-topic. A question on hold is not meant to be punitive, it's meant to prevent lengthy debates with no definitive answer (try Googling `should I use the Oxford comma`).